# I have a function that grabs the vertices of a line feature--why aren't the full lines getting processed?

Tags: arcpy, geometry, cursor

I am writing a function called getVertices. It uses arcpy to take a line feature class and turn it into an array of vertex lat/longs. It is a part of a larger script.

Here is the function:

```
def getVertices(line_feature):

    vertices =[]
    desc = arcpy.Describe(line_feature)
    shape_field = desc.shapeFieldName
    cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(line_feature)

    for row in cursor:
        shape = row.getValue(shape_field)
        part = shape.getPart(0)

        for point in part:
            coordinates = (point.X, point.Y)
            vertices.append(coordinates)

    return vertices
```

It does not work with all line feature classes, however. After processing many different line feature classes, I am seeing that in some of them only a chunk of the line is being processed--maybe the first 30 vertices, for example, or 3 vertices in the middle of the line.

I can't pin down if this is an issue in the function or in the line feature. To be clear, these are simple lines. I've double checked that the line features have no gaps in them.

What could the issue be?

EDIT: Here is the solution, which accounts for the multipart features lurking in my data.

```
def getVertices(line_feature):

    vertices =[]
    desc = arcpy.Describe(line_feature)
    shape_field = desc.shapeFieldName
    cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(line_feature)

    for row in cursor:
        shape = row.getValue(shape_field)
        part = shape.getPart()
        for p in part:

            for point in p:
                coordinates = (point.X, point.Y)
                vertices.append(coordinates)

    return vertices
```

Comment: You may have multiple Parts in a Line. Try adding a For loop, for part in parts.

Comment: @klewis when I add an additional loop, I get the error "Point object is not iterable"

Comment: If you have access to `da` cursors, there's an option `explode_to_points` that will give you all the vertices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, `shape.getPart(0)` equals to `shape.getPart()[0]` which just lists the first part's array/points. Therefore, you need to iterate parts not the points of the first part. For example the code below is the correct iteration for any shape row:

```
part = shape.getPart()
for p in part:
    for point in p:
        coordinates = (point.X, point.Y)
        vertices.append(coordinates)
```

Comment: I get the error "Point object is not iterable"

Comment: Sorry I forgot the part related to your real problem. you should revise `part` as `part = shape.getPart()`

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through all parts. This requires using `.partCount` and `range`.

```
def getVertices(line_feature):

    vertices =[]
    desc = arcpy.Describe(line_feature)
    shape_field = desc.shapeFieldName
    cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(line_feature)

    for row in cursor:
        shape = row.getValue(shape_field)
        for i in range (shape.partCount):
            part = shape.getPart(i)

            for point in part:
                coordinates = (point.X, point.Y)
                vertices.append(coordinates)

    return vertices
```